# Equating the coefficients to get following relation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I have a system of differential equations as follows:

```
EQ1=(-2*a*k + 3*k^2*\[Alpha] + \[Mu])*U[\[Eta]] - (1/3)*(\[Beta] + 2*\[Theta])*U[\[Eta]]^3 - \[Alpha]*Derivative[2][U][\[Eta]]==0
```

and

```
EQ2= (c + k^2*(a - k*\[Alpha]))*U[\[Eta]] + (-b + k*\[Beta])*U[\[Eta]]^3 - (a - 3*k*\[Alpha])*Derivative[2][U][\[Eta]]==0
```

I want to equate the same power terms in EQ1 and EQ2 to each other. So, I want to get the following relation:

```
\[Alpha] = (a \[Beta])/(3 b - 2 \[Theta])
```

and

```
\[Mu] = c + k (a (2 + k) - k (3 + k) \[Alpha])
```

I can equate them by using copy-paste and I get

```
coeff1=    (-2 a k + 3 k^2 \[Alpha] + \[Mu]) == (c + k^2 (a - k \[Alpha]))
coeff2=-(1/3) (\[Beta] + 2 \[Theta]) == (-b + k \[Beta])
coeff3=(a - 3 k \[Alpha]) == -\[Alpha]
```

Now I want to get the following relation from the system above

```
\[Alpha] = (a \[Beta])/(3 b - 2 \[Theta])
```

and

```
\[Mu] = c + k (a (2 + k) - k (3 + k) \[Alpha])
```

But I can not get `\[Alpha]` and `\[Mu]` like above using the following code:

```
Solve[{coeff1 &&coeff2 &&coeff3 }, {\[Alpha], \[Mu]}]
```

how to write a good code for both this question and other similar questions.

Comment: `! Eliminate[! And @@ {EQ1, EQ2}, {U[\[Eta]], U''[\[Eta]]}] // Simplify`?  May not work if the system is not polynomial-ish in the variables.  It seems to give something different, so maybe you're equating only some things? (The idea comes from the docs for `SolveAlways[]`, q.v.)

Comment: This is maybe a bit closer: `Equal @@ CoefficientList[{EQ1, EQ2} /. Equal -> Subtract, {U[\[Eta]], U''[\[Eta]]}] // Solve`

Comment: Thank you. I think I am misunderstood.  I edited the post.

Comment: Yes, your second suggestion is quite closer. If we can find just `\[Alpha]` and  `\[Mu]` instead of `\[Theta]` and `a`, I will be done.

Comment: Dear @Michael E2, As a similar question; How to divide the same power terms in EQ1 and EQ2 to each other like ` `Divide @@ CoefficientList[{EQ1, EQ2} /. 
   Equal -> Subtract, {U[\[Eta]], U''[\[Eta]]}]`.  Then, I want to equate the 3 proportions to each other and to solve it. Like `-(\[Alpha]/(-a + 3 k \[Alpha])) == (-2 a k + 3 k^2 \[Alpha] + \[Mu])/(   c + k^2 (a - k \[Alpha])) == (-\[Beta] - 2 \[Theta])/(   3 (-b + k \[Beta])) // Solve[#, {\[Mu], \[Beta]}] & // Simplify`

Comment: Assuming `Indeterminate` results only from missing terms, which is the case in this example, then `Divide @@ CoefficientList[{EQ1, EQ2} /. Equal -> Subtract, {U[\[Eta]], U''[\[Eta]]}] // Flatten // DeleteCases[Indeterminate] // Apply@Equal` gives the equation of the ratios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following what you want?

```
        CoefficientList[
      First[#], {U[η], U''[η]}] & /@ (EQ1 == EQ2) // 
   LogicalExpand // Solve[#, {α, μ, β}] & // Simplify
(* {{α -> a/(1 + 3 k),
     μ -> (c + 3 c k + 2 a k (1 + k)^2)/(1 + 3 k),
     β -> (3 b - 2 θ)/(1 + 3 k)}} *)
```

Comment: It is almost what I want. Only difference is `\[Mu] = c + k (a (2 + k) - k (3 + k) \[Alpha])` .

Comment: Revised to get a bit closer

Comment: As a similar question; How to divide the same power terms in EQ1 and EQ2 to each other like ` `Divide @@ CoefficientList[{EQ1, EQ2} /. 
   Equal -> Subtract, {U[\[Eta]], U''[\[Eta]]}]`.  Then, I want to equate the 3 proportions to each other and to solve it. `-(\[Alpha]/(-a + 3 k \[Alpha])) == (-2 a k + 3 k^2 \[Alpha] + \[Mu])/(   c + k^2 (a - k \[Alpha])) == (-\[Beta] - 2 \[Theta])/(   3 (-b + k \[Beta])) // Solve[#, {\[Mu], \[Beta]}] & // Simplify`